# k-size possible number combinations ordered by each sum

Tags: performance, algorithm, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

Given a set of `n` numbers; What is the code that generate all possible `k`-size subsets in descending order (decreasing each sum of values)?

**Example:**

`Set={9,8,6,2,1}` => `n=5` and `k=3`. So the *output* is:

```
[9,8,6] 
[9,8,2]
[9,8,1]
[9,6,2]
[9,6,1]
[8,6,2]
[8,6,1]
[9,2,1]
[8,2,1]
[6,2,1]
```

It is preferred the most efficient algorithm, but the algorithm with NP-Complete complexity (`n` choose `k` permutations) is the answer yet.
One-by-one generation in the `Matlab Code` is preferred for implementation. Or a solution that the maximum size of the ordered list in it can be determined (by this, for greater n and k, one may use an approximation and return specific size of this list without computing all possibilities).
***Note:*** 
1)Please give attention to the position of [9,2,1] in this ordered list. So index ordering is not the correct answer.
2)This may be a type of [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: @moksef Divakar's comment gives what you want, not just the size. Try `nchoosek([9 8 6 2 1], 3)`

Comment: @Luis: Thanks. This instruction didn't meet the note 1 above.

Comment: `combs = nchoosek(Set,3), [~,ind] = sort(combs(:,2),'descend'), output = combs(ind,:)`

Comment: @ Divakar: this only solve the example. but seems that doesn't work for other n and k values. see the 'Set' in the example by k=2.

Comment: In @Divakar's answer, change the second line to `[~,ind] = sort(sum(combs,2),'descend');` This will sort with respect to the sum of each row.

Comment: it seems it can solve the main problem. but for greater n and k, one may use an approximation, and want the first 'max-size' combinations. it is fruitful if a number of output generated in each iteration (while increasing the number of iterations, leads to more combinations and better approximation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Divakar, Yvon, and Luis, one of the possible answers to this question:
There are sorted set combinations in the `SSC`, so

```
combs = nchoosek(Set,k);
[~,ind] = sort(sum(combs,2),'descend');
SSC = combs(ind,:);
```

if you want the index of each number array in the `Set` (has unique numbers), with `num_arr` index in `SSC` use this code

```
for i=1:k
    Index(i)=find(SSC(num_arr,j)==Set(1,:));
end
```

this code returns `[1,3,5]` for `[9,6,1]` in `Index`.
**for greater n**
In this case, the computation is very time-consuming or even is impractical. An approximation may solves this issue, for such situations, you can find the first arbitrary answer by modifying the `nchoosek.m` in the `Matlab`.

Comment: In order to complete this answer, it is helpful that 'nchoosek.m' modifications are mentioned.